# Translate function

Tags: processing, translate

Can someone explain to me how to use the translate function while using processing ?

```java
int startposition =0;
    
void setup(){   
   size(500,500);
}   

void draw(){        
   background(255); 
   ﬁll(0);  
   translate(startposition,50); 
   rect(0,  0,  200,  200); 
   ellipse(0,  0,  300,   200); 
   startposition = startposition    +  1;
}
```

Can someone explain to me what is the purpose of using translate here since we are already saying that startposition = startposition +1 ....

i don't understand what the translate function does

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, we have no idea what library you're using, or what the context is. If you post a [mcve] we're much more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: java function?? you must mean method. so which class? did you look at the javadoc? they usually describe it quite good

Comment: This is processing...

Comment: @JonSkeet can you help me with that please, i just edited the question

Comment: @sharonbn can you have a look please

Comment: how is this related to java ?!? I just read that the processing compiler turns it into java code. however, no java programmer can help you here

Comment: our prof told us to learn processing since it has almost the same syntax as java

Comment: well... your prof doesn't know java.  java major construct is the class, not function. java has a main() for entry point. this seems more like a script language to me

Comment: and the poor source formatting doesn't help either

Comment: actually, it looks more like C than java ...

Comment: why do you say poor formatting  ? i can't be more detailed than this....

Comment: this is the actual way you write processing.......

Comment: We still don't know what library is providing those methods, unless it's part of processing itself (which I'd never heard of before now). As for the formatting - a good IDE will help you format the code a *lot* more readably. See https://processing.org/examples/rollover.html for an example of fairly conventional formatting.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 3):

Questions like these are best answered by reading [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/).

[Here](https://processing.org/reference/translate_.html) is the reference for the `translate()` function:

> Specifies an amount to displace objects within the display window. The x parameter specifies left/right translation, the y parameter specifies up/down translation, and the z parameter specifies translations toward/away from the screen. Using this function with the z parameter requires using P3D as a parameter in combination with size as shown in the above example.
>
> Transformations are cumulative and apply to everything that happens after and subsequent calls to the function accumulates the effect. For example, calling translate(50, 0) and then translate(20, 0) is the same as translate(70, 0). If translate() is called within draw(), the transformation is reset when the loop begins again. This function can be further controlled by using pushMatrix() and popMatrix().

**Examples:**

```java
translate(30, 20);
rect(0, 0, 55, 55);
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [processing.org](https://processing.org/reference/images/translate_0.png))</sub>

```java
// Translating in 3D requires P3D
// as the parameter to size()
size(100, 100, P3D);
// Translate 30 across, 20 down, and
// 50 back, or "away" from the screen.
translate(30, 20, -50);
rect(0, 0, 55, 55);
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [processing.org](https://processing.org/reference/images/translate_1.png))</sub>

```java
rect(0, 0, 55, 55);  // Draw rect at original 0,0
translate(30, 20);
rect(0, 0, 55, 55);  // Draw rect at new 0,0
translate(14, 14);
rect(0, 0, 55, 55);  // Draw rect at new 0,0
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [processing.org](https://processing.org/reference/images/translate_2.png))</sub>

In other words, the `translate()` function moves the drawing canvas so that any subsequent calls to functions like `rect()` or `ellipse()` will be offset. This enables you to move the "camera" around without changing the position of all of your on-screen objects.

Notice that you're drawing your rectangle and circle at position `0,0`. You aren't using the `startposition` variable as their positions. That's why you have to call `translate()` to move them around. You could get rid of the call to `translate()`, but you'd have to use the `startposition` variable as the position then.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
startposition = startposition +  1;
```

This line is not going to do anything if you leave it without translate. Translate actually changes the current origin of the drawing canvas. The origin is normally in top left corner and starts from (0,0);

So that translate will make everything that is drawn after to be at `startposition` pixels from the x origin which is 0.

To see what I mean try running the program with translate and without and you will see the difference.